# CoucDB in go Operatoer

Tags: couchdb

I have a data set in couch db where its look like this. The dates are all integers.

```
Date          | name | address
1544054400000 |adrian| asasad
1544227200000 |john  | asasad
1543980154648 |john  | asasad
```

I want to query out those where it is more than 1544054400000 and less than 1544227200000.

My query string looks like this

```
queryString := "{\"selector\":{\"docType\":\"" + Person + "\", \"date\":{\"$gte\":" + dateFrom + "}, \"date\":{\"$lte\":" + dateTo + "}}}"
```

However, it is returining me all results.

From what I know this is already an implicit 'AND' to query the data.

Can anyone advise?

update: I tried this

```
"{\"selector\":{\"$and\":\"[\"docType\":\"" + PREFIX_STicket + "\", \"betDate\":{\"$gte\":" + dateFrom + "},\"betDate\":{\"$lte\":" + dateTo + "}]}}"
```

But it said that

```
(status: 500, message: Query string is not a SELECT SQL expression or couchdb query expression: [{\"selector\":{\"$and\":\"[\"docType\":\"4DTicket\", \"betDate\":{\"$gte\":1544169025539},\"betDate\":{\"$lte\":1544169025539}]}}]), cause=null}",
```

Comment: Selectors do not use duplicate keys, and instead use the last one. You will need to add an `and` wrapper around your two `date` statements.

Comment: @HypnicJerk thank you can you advise how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not a valid JSON. The `$and` and `$or` operators should be arrays of objects.

Here's an updated version that should work:

```
"{\"selector\":{\"$and\":\"[{\"docType\":\"" + PREFIX_STicket + "\"}, {\"betDate\":{\"$gte\":" + dateFrom + "}},{\"betDate\":{\"$lte\":" + dateTo + "}}]}}"
```

Here's an easier example of the query with your variables:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "docType": PREFIX_STicket
      },
      {
        "betDate": {
          "$gte": dateFrom
        }
      },
      {
        "betDate": {
          "$lte": dateTo
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but didnt work. told me that 

status: 500, message: Query string is not a SELECT SQL expression or couchdb query expression:

Comment: Maybe the error is related to your adapter? How do you call the function?